# Calculating the average length of a column

Tags: awk

I have a task, where I have to count the average length of each word in a column with awk.

```
awk -F'\t'  '{print length ($8) } END  { print "Average = ",sum/NR}' file
```

In the output I get the total length of each line, but it does not count the average length, the output just says `Average = 0` which can not be the case because the printed lines before have numbers.

For better understanding i will copy paste the last line of the output here:

```
4
4
3
4
4
2
5
7
6
5
Average =  0
```

How do i need to change my code to get the average letters of the whole column as output?

Ty very much for your time and help :)

Comment: Where do you add values to variable sum?

Comment: i thought sum would just automatically take the values of the lengt i printed before. So i have to give sum manually the value of the lengh? And if yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [awk average part of column if lines (specific field) match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975943/awk-average-part-of-column-if-lines-specific-field-match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the output i get the total length of each line, but it does not count the average length, the output just says Average=0 which can not be the case because the printed lines before have numbers.

Because you're not adding lengths of columns to `sum`. Do it like this instead:

```
awk -F'\t' '{
  print length($8)
  sum += length($8)
}
END {
  print "Average =", sum/NR
}' file
```

Comment: Change `sum/NR` to `(NR ? sum/NR : 0)` or similar to avoid a divide by zero error if the input file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise a `sum` variable in a `BEGIN` section and accumulate the length of a column at each iteration.

I don't have your original file so I did a similar exercise for the 1st column of my `/etc/passwd` file:

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum += length($1); print length($1)} END{print "Average = " sum/NR}' /etc/passwd
```